# What type of application is putty?

Tags: .net, windows

What type of application is the Windows version of PuTTY.exe?

It looks like a Windows console application, but it doesn't respond to `Alt-Space` to open up the control menu.  I have the impression that every type of Windows application responds to `Alt-Space`.

---

> I thought my question was straightforward enough but it was down-voted at least three times. So I will provide additional information.
>
> I don't have a working mouse. I have four putty windows opened connected to four different sessions. I can do almost everything I want very efficiently, except I can't use the control menu of each putty window, because `Alt-Space` does not work on putty.exe. As a result I am unable to do things like move or resize the windows.
>
> I am hence curious how `Alt-Space` can be disabled or captured.

Comment: Terminal application...

Comment: Do you mean an application that outputs to just stdout and reads from stdin, the type that under Visual Studio is called a Console application?

Comment: "PuTTY is a free implementation of Telnet and SSH for Windows and Unix platforms, along with an xterm terminal emulator" Ctrl+d might be what you are looking for, this will send the EOF (end of file) char to the term and close it. You could just type 'exit' and get the same result.  what specifically are you trying to do from the menu?

Comment: No, my question is not on what the program does. My question is on the relationship of the program to the Windows environment. Why does it not respond to `Alt-Space`. I don't have a mouse.

Comment: it's a 'window' into another system. a *nix system at that. it's intent is to let you interact with that system in it's 'native tongue'. for that reason the windows commands that you might be accustom to may not (will not) work as expected.

Comment: I would guess 'console app' but i only use windows when I have to so some one else may correct what I  am saying.

Comment: Hint: Use Spy++ to investigate the window. Does it look like a console application (use `CMD.EXE`) or something else?

Comment: Or, of course, you could just use the source: http://tartarus.org/~simon-git/gitweb/?p=putty.git

Comment: After the edit, you have two questions: "how can Alt+Space be disabled or captured on Windows?", which is on topic for this site, but probably a duplicate; and "how can I enable Alt+Space in PuTTY?", which is potentially on topic for SuperUser, but is in the PuTTY FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a natively Windows application. While it does use *a* console, it doesn't use *the* Windows console - and it doesn't respond the way proper Windows applications should respond.

Instead, it is built on top of *xterm*, one of the many Unix/Linux terminal applications ("consoles"). To understand how to use it properly, just find the documentation for xterm.

However, if you check PuTTY's documentation, you'll find this question is already covered there - http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-altspace. Just use this config setting, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks!!  http://all-things-pure.blogspot.com/2011/08/expert-is.html